# Assemble and dissemble tools for vanity table

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture, design, desk

I am planning on building my girlfriend a vanity desk where she can apply her special make-up and all that lady stuff she enjoys as my anniversary gift. I have a concept in mind but one thing I know I want is for the legs, table, drawers and mirror to assemble and dissemble easily. The whole desk will be made out of wood because she loves wood.

My question is what are the nails or screws that make this possible. Just so I know so when I walk into home depot I will know what to look for.

Comment: How often do you expect to be disassembling and reassembling this? How long do you want it to take? Do you want to be able to do this without tools?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Not often, however, I am future-proofing this project because right now we just moved into a condo. When we move again, I don't want the movers to damage it. I don't want it to take too long. I think a day's work is reasonable. If by tools you mean a screwdriver or power drill, then no. I understand those kind of tools will be needed. I looked at Ikea's website and could not find the vanity desk I know my girlfriend likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ikea tend to use these widgets whose name you may have temporarily misplaced:

- "Furniture bolts"
- "Cam and pin" fixings

[image][image]

Just because Ikea doesn't stock it doesn't mean you cant do an *[Ikea hack](http://www.ikeahackers.net/)*

Comment: ooohhhhh, I see. Thank you! I'll give it a try and post back.

Comment: UPDATE: I gave up on the "assembly" goal for the project. Instead I'm nailing everything in and hoping for the best for future rearranging. @RedGrittyBrick I appreciate you showing me the Ikea hack but didn't find the table I know my gf would like. All-in-all it was a fun making a table :D